Fitting a policy to a target distribution $\pi$ with projections
Given a discrete target distribution $\mathbf{\pi}\in\Delta^n$, fitting a policy $\mathbf{p}$ to this distribution can be done via cross entropy loss, that is, minimizing $-\pi^\top \log \mathbf{p}$.
Suppose now that $n$ is very large, so that we cannot observe all of $\pi$ directly. Instead, we wish to train via an iterative process, where at each step $i$, we have access to a projection of $\pi$ onto some lower dimensional simplex, say $\pi_i'\in\Delta^d$. I am trying to figure out how we can formulate a step-wise objective for $\mathbf{p}$ in terms of $\pi_i'$.
The naive thing to do would be to do something like a 'sub cross-entropy' loss, i.e., minimizing $-\pi_i'^\top \log \mathbf{p}'$, where $\mathbf{p}'$ is just $\mathbf{p}$ projected onto the same lower dimensional simplex as $\pi_i'$.
However, if possible, I would like the objective satisfy one additional condition. Fixing some step $i$, let $\mathbf{q}$ be the new policy after updating $\mathbf{p}$ given $\pi_i'$, and let $D\subset [n]$ be the $d$ vertices of the total $n$ simplex that comprise the $i$-th projection. I would like $\sum_{j\in D} p_j = \sum_{j\in D} q_j$. In words, I want to conserve probability mass to be conserved among the vertices in $D$ after the policy is updated. This seems a bit much to ask for, so perhaps an alternate condition would be $\sum_{j\in D} p_j \geq \sum_{j\in D} q_j$, that is, the updated probabilities take up less total mass than the original ones.
Naively doing the above 'sub cross-entropy loss' from above leads to the opposite behavior, where we get that $\sum_{j\in D} q_j \geq \sum_{j\in D} p_j$, which in effect leads the policy to be more heavily biased to things it has seen before.
I hope I have posed this question in a coherent way, and I am happy to clarify any points of confusion. I also appreciate any pointers to works related to this problem. Thank you in advance!
